# Databinding for Instances of class objects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

To preface this I am new to WPF, XAML and C#

I have been looking for that last two days now for a method to create a custom class object that will expose some properties.  I then want to bind some text boxes in the UI to those properties but I want to be able to do this for multiple instances of a class (Analog in my case).  I am sure this is something simple but I am not understanding how to approach this.

Example of the class:

```
class Analog
    {
        public string LblA0
        { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT:
I have figured out how to bind to a class but I am unsure how I would create another class instance to bind to separately.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.DataContext>
       <local:Analog/>
   </Grid.DataContext>
   <TextBlock x:Name="labelAnalog0" 
                   Text="{Binding LblA0, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

EDIT 2: ViewModel class?

```
class ViewModel
{
    public Analog Analog0
    { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response I edit my post to show how I am binding currently, I am just unsure of how to proceed.  I think I am not approaching binding properly?

Comment: "*multiple instances of the same class object*" does not make sense. An object is a class instance. You may create multiple instance of your Analog class (i.e. multiple objects) and use them as source objects for multiple Bindings. It is however unclear what exatcly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: As a note, it is pointless to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on a OneWay Binding. UpdateSourceTrigger only has an effect in TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: @Clemens I edit my post, you are right that is the question I am trying to ask

Comment: You may create a ViewModel class with multiple properties of type Analog. Then assign an instance of the ViewModel class to the DataContext property of the view (usually the Window) and bind to the different Analogs by `Text="{Binding Analog1.LblA1}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay thanks to Clemens I think I understand how to solve this.
Here are the classes I have made:

```
    class Analog
{
    public Analog(string s)
    {
        lblA = s;
    }
    private string lblA;
    public string LblA
    {
        get
        {
            return lblA;
        }
        set
        {
            lblA = value;
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel
{
    Analog analog0 = new Analog("test");
    Analog analog1 = new Analog("test2");
    public Analog Analog0
    {
        get
        {
            return analog0;
        }
    }
    public Analog Analog1
    {
        get
        {
            return analog1;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<TextBlock x:Name="labelAnalog0" 
               Text="{Binding Analog0.LblA, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
               Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="labelAnalog1" 
               Text="{Binding Analog1.LblA, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
               Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

The call to change the datacontext in the mainpage

```
analogGrid.DataContext = new ViewModel();
```